# python count repetitions of elements in dictionary containing lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to efficiently transform a dictionary where each item is a list into a dataframe that counts the occurence of list elements across all keys:

```
mydict = {1:[1,3,5], 2:[1,4,6], 3:[5,6,7]}

## code to go from mydict to df

df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,3,4,5,6,7], "count":[2,1,1,2,2,1]})

    df
   id  count
0   1      2
1   3      1
2   4      1
3   5      2
4   6      2
5   7      1
```

The actual data will have 1000-2000 elemnts in the dicionary with each list having 5k-1.5mln elements. You can assume that the maximum value of the elements across all lists is bounded (by say 10mln).

Comment: Did you try writing code that produces the `{"id":[1,3,4,5,6,7], "count":[2,1,1,2,2,1]}` dictionary first, and then just passing it to the DataFrame constructor? Alternately, did you try writing code that produces a dict like `{1: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 1}` and proceeding from there?

Comment: what have You tried so far to to count the occurences?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` module. Something like code bellow:

```py
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for l in mydict.values():
    c.update(l)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':c.keys(), 'count':c.values()})
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in module `collections.Counter` can be used to get the number of elements.

Import to use it.

```py
from collections import Counter
```

Extract the value of `mydict` before counting.

```py
mydict_values = []
for v in mydict.values():
    mydict_values += v

# [1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7]
```

The element name to be counted will be the key.

```py
count = Counter(mydict_v)

# Counter({1: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 3: 2, 4: 2, 7: 2})
```

`.items()` to get a list of `(key, value)`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=count.items(),
        columns=['id', 'count'])

#    id  count
# 0   1      4
# 1   3      2
# 2   5      4
# 3   4      2
# 4   6      4
# 5   7      2
```